# Formatting ip:port into array

Tags: php, arrays, ip

I have a raw txt list of ip addresses in `127.0.0.1:80` format. 
What would be the easiest way to convert that list into this:

```
array(
    array('1.179.197.9', '88080'),
    array('1.234.45.50', '3128'),
    array('103.1.48.76', '8088'),
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode)

Answer (score 0):

This is one way ...

```
<?php

$ipAddresses = file('ipaddresses.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$ipAddrArray = [];
foreach ($ipAddresses as $ip) {
        $ipAddrArray[] = explode(':',$ip);
}
var_dump($ipAddrArray);
```

**ipaddresses.txt**

> 127.0.0.1:80
>
> 4.3.2.1:12345

Comment: this produces result that look like this:

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$ipAddressFileArray = file('ip-address.txt');

$ipAddrArray = array();

foreach ($ipAddressFileArray as $ipAddressRaw) {

        $ipAddrRawArray[] = explode(':',$ipAddressRaw);
        $ipAddrTempArray = array($ipAddrRawArray[0], $ipAddrRawArray[1]);

        array_push($ipAddrArray, $ipAddrTempArray);
}

?>
```